# How to make a rounding function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rounding

In python, I'm trying to create a program without using most of the built in functions python has as an extra challenge for me. I was wondering how would I implement a rounding function in python similar to the python module. How would I do it.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```py
def rounding(number, decimal):
    return int(1 * number - 0.5)+1

print(rounding(36.9782, 1))
```

This round the number to a full number, but doesn't round the number to any decimal places. How would I do this?

Comment: there is no advantage of using custom implementations over the standard ones. And you still use built-in functions like int in your code

Comment: @recursive_tree I know I'm just trying to limit the number of functions that I do use.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why didn't you initially try `return int(1 * number + 0.5)` to get rid of the addition by 1?

Comment: I had no idea that would work. I'm pretty new to python so I'm trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, but your missing one thing. You need to times the number by 10 to the power of the number of digits, and then at the end divide it by that same number like this:

```py
def rounding(number, decimal=0):
    return (int(pow(10, decimal) * number - 0.5)+1) / pow(10, decimal)

print(rounding(36.9782, 3))
```

This gives the output of `36.878`. The reason that we set decimal to 0 in the function is so that when no decimal is given, it automatically round to a whole number, like the built in round function.